# VBA Macro Excel "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

Tags: excel, insert, identity, vba

I'm new in VBA Excel macro. I want to create a vba script to insert a record from Excel worksheet and I tried with a simple script for testing but I hit below error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'table' when
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF
>
> oConn.Execute "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table1] ON" strSQL5 = "INSERT INTO
>   [table1] ([ID],[Company],[EmployeeID],[Category]) VALUES
>   (2956,'ABCDSG','ABCDSG1600338','Documentation')"
>
> oConn.Execute strSQL5
>
> oConn.Execute "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table1] OFF"
>
> The error message occurs even though I've put SET IDENTITY_INSERT
>   [table1] ON.

Any idea what causing the error and how to fix it?

Thank you